# MongoDB getserver is not available anymore, how can I connect to my database

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I was trying to connect to mongoDB database but I figured out that gerserver function is not available anymore. Here is a part of my code that achieves this.I am getting error while I am tryng to create a database because I am trying to convert it implicitly(MongoDatabase db=client.GetDatabase("test")

```
string connectionString = "Server=localhost:27017";
        Console.WriteLine("Connection MongoDB");
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        //MongoServer server = client.GetServer()
        MongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("test");
```

Comment: What error are you getting. Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

The `MongoClient` constructor takes a [MongoDB connection URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/), not a .Net style connection string.

So it should be:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase("test");
```

Note that I also changed the type of `db` to `IMongoDatabase` as that's what's returned by `GetDatabase`.

Comment: Thanks it actually worked without an error but I cannot see my database "test" in the robomongo. Even after I compiled,run and refresh. It is not available in the robomongo

Comment: MongoDB won't create the database until you write something into it.

Comment: Okay then could you please tell me what is wrong with this? I am trying create my collection and write something into it. It gives an error for save method.  İmagine I have a book class
            Book me = new Book();
            me.Title = "Ben";
            me.ISBN = "123456";
            me.Publisher = "Ugur";
            collection.save(me);

Comment: @G.Rust Go ahead and post that as a new question. Be sure to include the error details.

Comment: Hey johnny, I figured out the problem and just wanted you to know. I was able to create my collection and write something into it by using InsertOneAsync function @JohnnyHK

Comment: @G.Rust Great! If this answered your question, click the check mark to the left of the answer to mark it accepted.

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial that compatible with the latest version of MongoDB? I want to learn how to do crud operations on MongoDB

Comment: @G.Rust Start [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/getting_started/quick_tour/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JohnnyHK